# ios - Cllocation in background

Tags: ios, notifications, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I am working on project in which I need to fire notification when user reaches particular place, even application in background. What is the best way to do this?

What I found is following.

```
locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

or

```
[sharedService.locationManager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

or

```
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
```

About `startUpdatingLocation` I am getting continuous notification on simulator and on ipod after 3-4 mins.
Documents says it will drain battery and appstore may not accept because this methods must be used by application like navigation types.

About `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` documents says it uses cellular network. I am not sure whether it wil work on ipod. On my ipod not working. Does this method needs sim card?
And how does this method works? Means should I walk some distance to get this method respond? I traveled 1-2 km but it did not work.

About `startMonitoringForRegion` I used

```
if([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled])
        NSLog(@"monitering enable");
    else
        NSLog(@"monitering not avail");
```

For Ipod I got `monitering not avail`. Also client checked on his iphone. He also did not got notification.

Please can some one explain me this method? If any other way of finding location in background then please tell.

Edit:
I am using startUpdatingLocation. On device it calls `didUpdateToLocation` method every after 5 mins. Will it use lot of battery? and appstore will accept this?

If I use startUpdatingLocation will appstore accept app? Since my need is just to give notification when user reach a particular place.

Answer (score 0):

According to the application requirement you describe I think that 
- startMonitoringForRegion:
is the best approach, look at Apple Doc snippet below...

**You can use the region-monitoring service to be notified when the user crosses a region-based boundary. Region monitoring applies both to geographical regions (represented by the CLCircularRegion class) and to beacon regions (represented by the CLBeaconRegion class). You region monitoring to detect boundary crossings of the specified region and you use those boundary crossings to perform related tasks. For example, upon approaching a dry cleaners, an app could notify the user to pick up any clothes that had been dropped off and are now ready.**

You app is not tracking or routing related application so using [locationManager startUpdateLocation] will be overly done I think.